# Is this function defined in terms of elliptic $\mathrm{K}$ integrals even?

Tags: functions, special-functions, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Let $R,z > 0$ be positive real constants, and consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$ f(v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(R+v)^2+z^2}}\ \mathrm{K}\!\left( \frac{4 R v}{(R+v)^2+z^2} \right)$$
where $\mathrm{K}(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, defined (using Wolfram *Mathematica*'s convention) by
$$ \mathrm{K}(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2 \theta}}. $$
Is $f$ an even function? Numerical tests suggest that it should be, but I can't find the right series of manipulations to demonstrate this analytically.

Comment: Okay, backtracking somewhat, one obvious thing to do is divide everything by $R^2$, and then you can relabel $v/R \mapsto v$, $z/R \mapsto z$ to get rid of $R$. Not much progress, but at least that leaves you fewer variables!

Comment: Right, sorted it out (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, cracked it. It's annoyingly simple in the end:
$$ K(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2{\theta}}} \\
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m(1-\cos^2{\theta})}} \\
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(1-m)+m\cos^2{\theta}}} \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-m}}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\frac{m}{m-1}\cos^2{\theta}}}  $$
and changing variables you conclude that
$$ K(m) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-m}} K\left( \frac{m}{m-1} \right), $$
with caveats about square roots. Turns out you're fine, since
$$ 1-m = 1- \frac{4v}{(1+v)^2+z^2} = \frac{(1+v)^2+z^2-4v}{(1+v)^2+z^2} = \frac{(1-v)^2+z^2}{(1+v)^2+z^2}, $$
clearly positive. And then you also have
$$ \frac{m}{m-1} = -\frac{4v}{(1+v)^2+z^2} \frac{(1+v)^2+z^2}{(1-v)^2+z^2} = \frac{-4v}{(1-v)^2+z^2} $$

(Obviously I've set $R=1$ here, which is fine because I can just divide $v$ and $z$ by it.) Hence you end up with the evenness you asked for.

Remark: the identity I proved above is basically [DLMF's 19.7.2's first equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E2), in different notation.

Comment: That should be a $4Rv$ in the numerator of the argument of `EllipticK`, not $2Rv$.

Comment: Ah, that's more interesting...

Comment: Fantastic! I think this is about as elegant a solution as I could have hoped for.

Comment: Yep, sometimes one just has to dig in and push the integrals around until they co-oporate :). Just don't ask me how to prove the AGM integral...

Comment: For searching purposes: the relation you proved is called the *imaginary modulus transformation*.